# Quarkus SSL Unrecognized configuration key

Tags: java, ssl, quarkus

i have a Quarkus project, with SSL enabled, and it can't even start the application.

```
Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-type" was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the dependency extension for this configuration is set or that you did not make a t...
Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.http.ssl.port" was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the dependency extension for this configuration is set or that you did not make a typo
Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-password" was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the dependency extension for this configuration is set or that you did not make a typo
Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.http.ssl" was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the dependency extension for this configuration is set or that you did not make a typo
```

I'm using JDK17

I have configured application.properties like this:

```
quarkus.http.ssl=true
quarkus.http.ssl.port=3000
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/verseny.iranyazur.hu/keystore.p12
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-password=password
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-type=PKCS12
```

I also have ssl in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-ssl</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-undertow</artifactId>
            </dependency>
```

The keystore file is valid:

```
Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SUN
Your keystore contains 1 entry
1, 13 Sept 2023, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): 73:21:26:CE:DA:D2:C9:06:B3:8B:09:8E:37:0F:A9:0B:BF:C2:6A:42:A3:2A:78:94:0C:8C:13:EA:28:95:A1:81
```

The keystore is also chmod 777-ed

I'd greatly appreciate any ideas and help on what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names of the properties you are using are incorrect. Check [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-vertx-http_quarkus-vertx-http-eclipse-vert.x-http) for the correct ones.